# How to get event pixel when I have coordinates in database

Tags: reactjs, openlayers-6

I have clicked on a coordinates and remove with the help of MouseEvent clientY and ClientX value. I have some coordinates in database and I want to hit them same as it clicked as event. I have used bellow code.

```
const pixel = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(coordinates);
event = {}
event.clientX = pixel[0];
event.clientY = pixel[1];
simulateSingleClick(map, event);
```

But not able to click because event's clientY and above clientY value has lot of different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The map viewport is a viewport within the client viewport https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect so unless you have a full page map you will need to add the left and top offsets of that

```
const vpClient = map.getViewport().getBoundingClientRect();
const pixel = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(coordinates);
event = {}
event.clientX = vpClient.left + pixel[0];
event.clientY = vpClient.top + pixel[1];
simulateSingleClick(map, event);
```

Comment: Your answer is really useful for me. Thank you, sir